# Scala method multiple parameter groups with overload

Tags: scala, overloading

Trying to overload a method with multiple parameter groups, where the 2nd parameter type differs doesn't seem to work. This will not compile:

```
class Foo {
  def boo(a: String)(b: String): Unit = ()
  def boo(a: String)(b: Int): Unit = boo(a)(b.toString)
}
```

I would have thought that it would be compiled into `boo(String, String)` and `boo(String,Int)` methods and thus be ok in the JVM. But I guess not.

What I'm looking for is a workaround - I want to keep the parameter groups and the overloaded name so its transparent to the caller, but any other hacks are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an intermediary layer that has an overloaded `apply` method:

```
object Foo {
    def boo(a: String) = BooMaker(a)
    case class BooMaker(a: String) {
        def apply(b: String): Unit = ()
        def apply(b: Int): Unit = apply(b.toString)
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call `Foo.boo("a")("b")` or `Foo.boo("a")(1)`, but introduces the potentially undesired intermediary tier.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be curried? It won't compile because of the partial application. The following should compile just fine.

```
class Foo {
  def boo(a: String, b: String): Unit = ()
  def boo(a: String, b: Int): Unit = boo(a, b.toString)
}
```

If you can give more context to your actual use case, it might help with giving a better answer.

Comment: It needs to be curried because I want the 2nd parameter group for block style invocation. It's for a DSL.